# Phonegap fileTransfer.Download give me an error code 3

Tags: cordova, file-transfer

I'm creating my first web application using Cordova version is 6.3.1.

In this app I need to be able to download a file to the phone and then open it, but I can't seem to get pass how to download the file.

Im using the file-transfer code from Cordova's doc page. Everything is installed with CLI.
This is how far I've come:

```
function downloadfile(){


var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    var uri = encodeURI("http://s14.postimg.org/i8qvaxyup/bitcoin1.jpg");
     var fileURL =  "/storage/DCIM/myFile";
    fileTransfer.download(

        uri,
        fileURL ,
        function(entry) {
            alert("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
            alert("download start");
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log("download error source " + error.source);
            console.log("download error target " + error.target);
            console.log("download error code" + error.code);
        }
    );
}

<access origin=".*" />
```

When I click on download button the code gives me an error Download button code

```
<button id="download"   style="margin-top: 78px;" class="button button-block button-positive" type="button" onclick="downloadfile()">Download File</button>
```